# Code is not giving me the max number out of the list

Tags: python

I'm supposed to input two different list, that part works, then I have to find the biggest numbers of each lists, that's where the problem is, it seemingly just picks out a random number as the max. After that the code has to show which of the max numbers is bigger, that part works just fine.

```
File = open("Answers.txt", "w")
List_1 = []
List_2 = []
Numbers_1 = input("How many number do you want in the first list: ")
i = 0
while i < int(Numbers_1):
    A = input("Number: ")
    List_1.append(A)
    i += 1
Biggest_num_1 = max(List_1)

File.writelines(str(List_1) + "\n")
File.writelines("Biggest number " + (max(List_1)) + "\n")

Numbers_2 = input("How many number do you want in the second list: ")
i = 0
while i < int(Numbers_2):
    A = input("Number: ")
    List_2.append(A)
    i += 1
Biggest_num_2 = max(List_2)

File.writelines(str(List_2) + "\n")
File.writelines("Biggest number is " + (max(List_2)) + "\n")

if int(Biggest_num_1) > int(Biggest_num_2):
    File.writelines(f"The biggest number is between the lists is {Biggest_num_1} and 
is from list 1")
elif int(Biggest_num_2) > int(Biggest_num_1):
    File.writelines(f"The biggest number is between the lists is {Biggest_num_2} and 
is from list 2")
else:
    File.writelines("The biggest numbers in the lists are equal")
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, not an integer. You need to convert your string into integers.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loops, convert A into an integer before you add it to the list:

```
while i < int(Numbers_1):
    A = input("Number: ")
    List_1.append(int(A))
    i += 1
```